# LINQ / Multiple GroupBy. Which is the proper one, recursive usage or chain usage?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose that I have a `DataTable` which I want to make 3 level grouping(or even more in future). Just to simplify I'll ask for 2 levels.

```
DataTable dt = getTable();
```

Using LINQ, I can think of 2 ways. First,

```
var chainWay = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(dr => new { A = dr["A"], B = dr["B"] })
                                      .GroupBy(g => new { g.Key.A });
foreach (var group in chainWay)
{
    foreach (var group2 in group)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in group2)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and the second,

```
var recursiveWay = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(dr => dr["A"])
                          .Select(g => new { g.Key, G = g.GroupBy(dr => dr["B"]) });
foreach (var group in recursiveWay)
{
    foreach (var group2 in group.G)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in group2)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Which way is the proper one? First, second or any other?

Will there be any performance difference?

Please keep in mind that I want to make a generalization of this (for more levels).

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: I would go with the first option as it's more readable, as for this `Will there be any performance difference?` - benchmark it and find out.

Comment: These don't even produce the same results, so comparing them for performance is rather pointless when they don't actually do the same thing.

Comment: @Servy You are right. They are not the same types, but are very similar. With a very small difference I can iterate and do the same action(just edited the question). If I can decide which one to prefer, then it is easy to adapt the loops.

Comment: @Servy I think he realizes the data structures aren't binary compatible, but the resulting structure is semantically the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be bordering on "primarily based on opinion."  Here's a third option which I have used numerous times. It's more verbose, but it I think it makes the structure clearer. It's also easy to see the repeating nature of the nesting, so it's easy to generalize to more groupings.

```
var query = source.GroupBy(
    x => x.A,
    (a, aGroup) => new
    {
        A = a,
        Items = aGroup.GroupBy(
            x => x.B,
            (b, bGroup) => new
            {
                B = b,
                Items = bGroup
            })
    });
```

The anonymous objects being instantiated could of course be replaced with your appropriate classes.

Comment: A way of recursive one. Thanks for reminding me that `GroupBy` has other overloads.